# My css imges js path is changed after using of mod_rewrite

Tags: html, css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have changed my url from

```
http://example.com/course.php?id=1001
```

To

```
http://example.com/course/1001
```

but after changing the url of all the css js and images is not working

I have use this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^course/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ coursedetails.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: then you should exempt css/image urls from the rewrite... e.g. `RequestCond -f %{REQUEST_URI}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> one solution is that use absolute path (ex /css, or /js rather than just css/, /js but this is not looks a reliable solution since we've to change it on all files,

This is because your relative URIs have their base changed. Originally, the base is `/` when the page is `/course.php?id=1001`, and the browser properly fills in relative links with the `/` base. But when the browser goes to a page like `/course/1001` the base suddenly becomes `/course/` and it tries to append that in front of all relative URLs and thus none of them load.

You can either make your links absolute, or change the URI base in the header of your pages (inbetween the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/">
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1st method

If those parts are hardcoded you could simply change your links adding `../` before :

`path/to/my/assets/style.css`

would become

`../path/to/my/assets/style.css`

---

### 2nd method

You could use `.htaccess` as Marc suggested (assuming your assets folder is `assets` :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^course/assets/(.*) assets/$1
```

Or using a redirection

```
RedirectMatch 303 /courses/assets(.*) /assets/$1
```

> Note 303 See Other response code which seems more appropriate http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4