# Mod_rewrite - CSS, JS and Images not working

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

it's my first time I am asking a Question here.
I have a problem with mod_rewrite.

I have the following filesystem structure:

```
site_new/stylesheets/layout.css  
site_new/javascript/somescript.js  
site_new/hallendetails.php  
site_new/etc...
```

Now I tried to redirect my php Page to an html file via mod_rewrite.
It works fine, my .htaccess looks like that:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /site_new/  
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$ hallendetails.php?id=$1&halle=$2 [L]
```

**The orignial url is:**

```
localhost/site_new/hallendetails.php?id=01&halle=Heimspielhalle_Gaissacher_Strasse
```

**The "new" url then is:**

```
localhost/site_new/01/Heimspielhalle_Gaissacher_Strasse.html
```

Now all my CSS, JS and Image files are broken.
They are included like that:
`type="text/css" href="stylesheets/layout.css"`

But after redirecting they are searched in

```
/site_new/01/stylesheets/layout.css
```

I think I need a RewriteCond, but I don't know how to write it. I tried lots of ways, but I don't get it.

Please help!

Comment: Try it by typing `type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/layout.css"` (see the additional `/` at the beginning of the path).

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, but then it's taking the link localhost/stylesheets/layout.css and not localhost/site_new/stylesheets/layout.css. So I can add ../, but than I have to re-chage it when I upload to the Webserver every time.

Comment: Related :- 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212900/my-css-imges-js-path-is-changed-after-using-of-mod-rewrite/31218509#31218509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the absolute path to css,images,js when using mod_rewrite